# Editing a module from another component

Tags: joomla-4.x

Suppose I want to edit the field ("Home") of a module (say mod_breadcrumbs) from edit.php file of another module.I want to use the radio button inside another module instead of using here. Is this possible in joomla 4. Please refer the screenshot for the "home" field, I mentioned above.[image]

Comment: if this answer was helpful to you I would appreciate it if you would accept the answer so that it at least shows your issue has been resolved and no further action is likely. It is not compulsory to accept an answer, meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, but it does help encourage people like me to take the time to answer more questions for you and other people.

Answer (score 1):

It would be very difficult but it could be done if you wanted to write enough code.

The values for each setting are stored in the **params** field for each instance of the module in the **#__modules** table. As it is possible to have more than one instance of a  module your code would need to handle this to make sure you are updating the right module or all of them if that is your requirement.

Converting it to a radio check button is easy enough, just change to that type in the .xml file of of your other Module.

Comment: I actually want to edit the the published/unpublished state of a module from inside a component (say com_menu). I want to edit the the published/unpublished state of a module from inside of a menu item in com_menus. I have changed the title to make things more clear